# How to achieve a repeating circular shape like the 'Sam Rockwell - Moon' poster in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, patterns

I need help for making this circular shape in Adobe Illustrator.

I assume it is basically just making circle shapes over and over again using the strokes and putting it inside each other over and over again?

Is there a better method to create this circular pattern?

[image: Poster for the movie Moon starring Sam Rockwell]

Comment: And the more interesting question: how to create one without a moiré pattern?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the **Polar Grid Tool**. This is what it's for.

Tap the <kbd>↑</kbd> arrow on the keyboard while dragging to add rings. Tap the <kbd>↓</kbd> arrow while dragging to remove rings. Tap <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd> arrows to remove or add dividing lines.

[image]

Comment: ooh nice, never even seen that before! haha

Answer (score 10):

As you have already selected the correct answer, this is for anyone who want to know the exact steps.

Create your smallest circle using the ellipse tool, then create your biggest circle around it (copy the smaller circle then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste in place and hold <kbd>shift</kbd> to scale up (On PC)); highlight the two and choose `Object > Blend > Make`

[image]

This will start the path between the smallest object and the largest. Then select `Object > Blend > Blend Options` and choose `Specified Steps` to choose the amount of steps you want between your smallest and largest circle:

[image]

Once you're happy with the amount of circles, you can select `Object > Expand` to release the circles so you can further edit them if you wish:
[image]

Answer (score 9):

1. Create the largest one.
2. Then create the smallest one via `Edit > Copy` (<kbd>Ctrl/Option</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) -> `Edit > Paste in front` (<kbd>Ctrl/Option</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) -> scale down.
3. Then select both objects, go to `Object -> Blend` and select
   `specified steps`.